# Scale centered image to browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like the images on to be scaled to 80% of the browser window's height. What is a simple and universal way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS:

```
img { height:80%; }
```

or

```
img { height:80vh; }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had hoped it would be that simple. I don't see any result [here](http://www.leecorbin.co/test/index-stack-2.html) though.

Comment: You commented out the CSS.

Comment: I removed the comments and don't see any [difference](http://www.leecorbin.co/test/index-stack-2.html).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? It seems to be working to me. You can tell the difference if you change the height to 10%.

Comment: I'd like the images to be scaled to 80% of the browser window's height. With your solution, when I change the size of the window in FF or Safari, the images remain the same size.

Comment: [Yes](http://www.leecorbin.co/test/index-stack-2.html). Here's [an example](http://www.morganstudio.co.uk/) of what I'm trying to do. Notice how the image is reduced or enlarged as you change the size of the window.

Comment: I am not sure about FF and Safari as I don't have the browsers. It worked fine in Chrome when I tested 80vh.

Comment: The table I'm using to center the image on the page is what is preventing it from scaling as the browser window is resized. I removed it [here](http://www.leecorbin.co/test/index-onclick-2.html). Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any javascript to do this it is very simple. You should add html and body width and height to 100%.
Here is jfiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/vz7q2bnk/

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/500" />
</body>
</html>

<!--css part-->
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
img{height:100%; width:auto; vertical-align: top;}
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented [your solution](http://www.leecorbin.co/test/index-stack-1.html) but don't see any result.